# Trying to understand POSIX Threads

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

I am trying to get a grasp on the use of POSIX threads and created a simple program that simply increments a global variable by 10.  On sometimes it runs all the way through fine, other it seg faults in random spots. While this type of issue seems to be a regular thing with threads, I cannot understand why this happens in such a simple example.  My current thought is maybe the parent is ending before due to not joining the threads, but if i try to join i seg fault on first thread...  The Join statement is left in but commented out.  Is Join used in correct syntax?  Is not preforming the join leading to the seg fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NUMPHILO 5

thread_t threads[NUMPHILO];  //array of threads 
pthread_mutex_t mutex;        // initialize mutex

int x = 5;          //for test
int y = 10;

int philofunct(){
    pthread_mutex_lock (&mutex);
    x = x+y;
    pthread_mutex_unlock (&mutex);
    printf("Philo fucntion x = %d\n",x);
    return x;
}


int main(){

    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUMPHILO; i++){  
        printf("creating thread[%i]\n",i);
        if( pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, (void *)philofunct(),(void *) &i) != 0)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s", strerror(errno));
//      pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);  
//      printf("Threads Joined\n");
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
    printf("Threads created\n");
}
```

output:

```
creating thread[0]
Philo fucntion x = 15
creating thread[1]
Philo fucntion x = 25
creating thread[2]
Philo fucntion x = 35
creating thread[3]
Philo fucntion x = 45
creating thread[4]
Philo fucntion x = 55
Threads created
```

next time ran:

```
creating thread[0]
Philo fucntion x = 15
creating thread[1]
Philo fucntion x = 25
creating thread[2]
Philo fucntion x = 35
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

As always, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: printffing outside the lock.

Comment: @MartinJames POSIX requires all stdio functions (except `*_unlocked`) to be thread-safe even if the application does no locking at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem you have is here:

```
    if( pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, (void *)philofunct(),(void *) &i) != 0)
```

Look carefully, you are calling `philofunct()` instead of passing the function pointer to it.  Worse, you are passing the return value of `philofunct()`, which is some integer such as `15`, as the function pointer to `pthread_create()`.  Naturally, the thread will segv when it tries to execute code from an address such as `15`.

Once you define `philofunct()` correctly like this:

```
void *philofunct(void *arg)
```

You can then call `pthread_create()` without a cast:

```
    if( pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, philofunct,(void *) &i) != 0)
```

Also, if you want to join your threads, you should join your threads after they are all running.  If you join the thread in the creation loop, you will be waiting for each thread to finish before creating the next one.  So you would write it like this:

```
for (i=0;i<NUMPHILO; i++) {
    pthread_create(&threads[i], ...);
    // Other stuff...
}
for (i=0;i<NUMPHILO; i++)
    pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining where the join loop should be.  I figured I already had a loop, while not put it in there... Apparently there is a reason not to do that.  There does seem to be conflicting feelings on whether the printf should be inside the mutex or not, what is your take on this? My understanding has been it shouldn't matter.

Comment: @Tom Since you are printing `x` which is a shared resource, you should put the `printf` inside the mutex.  Otherwise, another thread could change the value of `x` before you print it, leaving you with a confusing printout (for example, duplicate values being printed out).

Answer (score 4):

I see several problems with your code before even considering what you want:

- You can't cast function pointers like that and expect a meaningful result. Instead, give the function the correct signature and cast the argument/return value at the edge of the function. But you usually don't actually need to use a return value.
- You are accessing the variable `x` outside of the section locked by the mutex.
- You are destroying the mutex without waiting for all the threads that are using it to exit. You need a second loop to `pthread_join` them all. Alternatively, you could `pthread_exit` the main thread instead of letting `main` terminate (and never destroy the mutex, which is not a leak since there's only one of them and its lifetime ends with the lifetime of the program), but killing the main thread sometimes makes funny kernel "bugs" happen.

Answer (score 1):

The main thread is destroying the mutex before the child threads are finished with it. `pthread_join` will solve the problem, but the `pthread_join` needs to be in a separate loop after all of the threads have been created.

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUMPHILO; i++) 
   pthread_join(threads[i],NULL);
```

The function signature for the `philofunct` is wrong. In general, if you need a cast, you're doing something wrong. (Yes, there are some cases where a cast is necessary and useful. This is not one of those cases.) The correct signature is

```
void *philofunct( void *arg );
```

and the correct call to `pthread_create` is

```
if( pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, philofunct, NULL) != 0)
```

Note that passing the address of `i` won't do what you want, but that's a separate question, and you haven't gotten to that point yet.